# Postgres - COALESCE syntax on insert

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, coalesce, null-coalescing-operator

I am trying to do an `INSERT` within **PostgreSQL** query but getting an error when I try to implement `COALESCE` operator..

What I try to accomplish is that if the id value in `team_member` if found, insert `created_by_team_member_id` column.

```
INSERT INTO publish_queue
(status, created_by_team_member_id = COALESCE(created_by_team_member_id,
       (SELECT id FROM team_member WHERE member_id = 1 AND team_id = 16 LIMIT 1))
)
VALUES ('Welcome!');
```

And the error:

> syntax error at or near "="\nLINE 15:
> created_by_team_member_id = COALESCE(created...\n

Comment: Apart from being far from valid SQL syntax, that doesn't make any sense to me: How should an `INSERT`, which creates a new row, update anything? Which row in which table should it update?

Comment: I updated my question, I thought of INSERT not Update.. I am new in writing sql queries and I was wondering where the COALESCE operator should be in case of an INSERT.. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Then why do you need `coalesce`? since this is a new row, there is no prior `created_by_team_member_id`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Can you provide some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it after the inserts?

Comment: Ah! I need the ID from the other table (team_member )matching those two parameters I inputed.. Should I do it otherwise than with coalesce? @LaurenzAlbe Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I am still not certain what you want to do, but perhaps it is

```
INSERT INTO publish_queue (status, created_by_team_member_id)
SELECT 'Welcome!',
       id
FROM team_member
WHERE member_id = 1
  AND team_id = 16 LIMIT 1;
```